# PyOpenGL segfault

Tags: python, opengl, pygame

I am following a tutorial and have identical code to the guy running the tutorial and have downloaded the same packages etc, yet I get an error and he does not. Any help explaining the error in the following code would be greatly appreciated. I should add that I have seen similar threads on here but no solution so far has helped. For reference, it returns the error

```
Fatal Python error: (pygame parachute) Segmentation Fault

Current thread 0x00000ba4 (most recent call first):

  File "C:/Users/00101010/PycharmProjects/3DPygame/textcompare.py", line 44 in main

  File "C:/Users/00101010/PycharmProjects/3DPygame/textcompare.py", line 63 in <module>

Process finished with exit code 3
```

Below is the code.

```
import pygame
from pygame import *
from OpenGL.GL import *
from OpenGL.GLU import *
import sys

vertices = (
    (1, -1, -1),
    (1, 1, -1),
    (-1, 1, -1),
    (-1, -1, -1),
    (1, -1, 1),
    (1, 1, 1),
    (-1, -1, 1),
    (-1, 1, 1)
)

edges = (
    (0, 1),
    (0, 3),
    (0, 4),
    (2, 1),
    (2, 3),
    (2, 7),
    (6, 3),
    (6, 4),
    (6, 7),
    (5, 1),
    (5, 4),
    (5, 7)
)


def Cube():
    glBegin(GL_LINES)
    for edge in edges:
        for vertex in edge:
            glVertex3fv(vertices[vertex])
    glEnd()


def main():
    pygame.init()
    displaysize = (800, 600)
    pygame.display.set_mode(displaysize, DOUBLEBUF | OPENGL)

    gluPerspective(45, (displaysize[0] / displaysize[1]), 0.1, 50.0)

    glTranslatef(0.0, 0.0, -5)

    while True:
        for i in pygame.event.get():
            if i.type == pygame.QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                sys.exit()

        glRotatef(1, 3, 1, 1)
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT)
        Cube()
        pygame.display.flip()
        pygame.time.wait(10)


main()
```

**Edit:**

The output of `sys.version` is `3.6.1 (v3.6.1:69c0db5, Mar 21 2017, 18:41:36) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)]`.

Running the example that only uses PyOpenGL results in the this error on line 35 in init (line 76 in the script):

```
OpenGL.error.GLError: GLError( err = 1282, description = b'invalid operation', baseOperation = glViewport, cArguments = (0, 0, 1366, 768) )
```

The error continues with this also:

```
freeglut (C:/Users/OOIOIOIO/PycharmProjects/OpenGLstuff/OpenGLtest.py‌​): fgInitGL2: fghGenBuffers is NULL
```

It's a fairly old toshiba satellite c660 laptop from circa 2010 with an Intel Pentium CPU P6100 and It doesn't have a dedicated graphics card.

Comment: I should add that I am using Python 3.6 64 bit (though I've tried it on 32 but also) and the guy doing the tutorial was using 3.4 but I doubt that this is a problem?

Comment: The code seems to work correctly. Are you watching Sentdex's opengl tutorial?

Comment: I am watching his tutorial yes, he's pretty good. I am also fairly sure the code should work correctly as you say, so it might be something to do with my setup. Any ideas?

Comment: I have changed the code a little in an attempt to fix it but his original code wasn't working either.

Comment: Have you tried to run the program from the command-line/terminal? Which Python versions do you have installed?

Comment: I have tried it on Python 3.6 32 and 64 bit, and I've not tried the whole program from the command line but a guy below who is also assisting me had me try part of it, it also crashed in a similar manner to above. I will try the whole thing as you suggested when I have time tomorrow, thanks for the suggestions thus far.

Comment: Running from the command line gives an error on the same line and I get a window saying "Python has stopped working"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Fatal Python error: (pygame parachute) Segmentation Fault
>
> pygame.display.set_mode() is failing.

That sounds really weird, because `pygame.display.set_mode()` isn't supposed to fail like that. If the specified display mode isn't supported, then pygame would fallback and use something else. But never straight up fail like that.

> The advantage is if your display mode is not available, pygame will emulate the display mode that you asked for.
>
> *– [Pygame Setting Display Modes](http://www.pygame.org/docs/tut/DisplayModes.html)*

Thus since you're dealing with a segfault it sounds like you're dealing with something unsupported and possibly old and outdated.

I've rewritten your code to only use PyOpenGL. *Can you verify whether you're able to run it when pygame isn't involved?*

```
import sys
from OpenGL.GL import *
from OpenGL.GLU import *
from OpenGL.GLUT import *


vertices = [
    (1, -1, -1),
    (1, 1, -1),
    (-1, 1, -1),
    (-1, -1, -1),
    (1, -1, 1),
    (1, 1, 1),
    (-1, -1, 1),
    (-1, 1, 1)
]

edges = [
    (0, 1),
    (0, 3),
    (0, 4),
    (2, 1),
    (2, 3),
    (2, 7),
    (6, 3),
    (6, 4),
    (6, 7),
    (5, 1),
    (5, 4),
    (5, 7)
]


def init(width, height):
    glViewport(0, 0, width, height)

    glClearColor(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0)

    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION)
    gluPerspective(45.0, (width / height), 0.1, 50.0)

    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW)
    glTranslatef(0.0, 0.0, -5.0)


def display():
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT)

    glRotatef(1.0, 3.0, 1.0, 1.0)

    glBegin(GL_LINES)
    for edge in edges:
        for vertex in edge:
            glVertex3fv(vertices[vertex])
    glEnd()

    glutSwapBuffers()


def resize(width, height):
    glViewport(0, 0, width, height)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    glutInit(sys.argv)
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_RGBA | GLUT_DOUBLE | GLUT_DEPTH)
    glutInitWindowSize(640, 480)
    glutInitWindowPosition(200, 200)

    glutCreateWindow(b"OpenGL")

    glutDisplayFunc(display)
    glutIdleFunc(display)
    glutReshapeFunc(resize)

    init(glutGet(GLUT_SCREEN_WIDTH), glutGet(GLUT_SCREEN_HEIGHT))

    glutMainLoop()
```

Note that if you get an error similar to this:

> OpenGL.error.NullFunctionError: Attempt to call an undefined function glutInit, check for bool(glutInit) before calling

Then it's because you don't have glut or the newer [freeglut](http://freeglut.sourceforge.net/) (you can [download precompiled binaries here](http://www.transmissionzero.co.uk/software/freeglut-devel/)).

Note that since `sys.version` returns `3.6.1 (v3.6.1:69c0db5, Mar 21 2017, 18:41:36) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)]` then better safe than sorry and download the *[freeglut 3.0.0 MSVC Package](http://www.transmissionzero.co.uk/software/freeglut-devel/)*. Since you're using 64-bit, make sure to take the 64-bit version of `freeglut.dll` (the zip contains both versions). Place `freeglut.dll` inside your project directory next to you Python script.

> It returned this error, line 35 in init, line 76 in module
>
> ```
>  OpenGL.error.GLError: GLError( err = 1282, description = b'invalid operation', baseOperation = glViewport, cArguments = (0, 0, 1366, 768) )
> ```
>
> The error continues with this also
>
> ```
> freeglut (C:/Users/OOIOIOIO/PycharmProjects/OpenGLstuff/OpenGLtest.py‌​): fgInitGL2: fghGenBuffers is NULL
> ```

That shouldn't happen. It sounds unlikely that a graphics card wouldn't support any form of OpenGL.
However considering that it had trouble with `glViewport()` (which has been core since 1.0). Then it sounds like that could be the case. Try running [OpenGL Extensions Viewer](http://realtech-vr.com/admin/glview) and see what it says.

> Intel Pentium CPU P6100

It looks like your CPU doesn't support OpenGL at all. [The specification doesn't even mention OpenGL at all](https://ark.intel.com/products/50175/Intel-Pentium-Processor-P6100-3M-Cache-2_00-GHz). In contrast to say this [Intel Core i7-7Y75](https://ark.intel.com/products/95441/Intel-Core-i7-7Y75-Processor-4M-Cache-up-to-3_60-GHz) (as a random example).

Comment: This sounds really weird, because I just tested the exact same as you. Python 3.6, PyCharm and Windows 64-bit. Could you try opening a command prompt and enter `python -c "import pygame; pygame.init(); pygame.display.set_mode((800, 600), pygame.OPENGL | pygame.DOUBLEBUF)"`. A window show appear and disappear immediately. The important factor is, does it show and error/crash?

Comment: Could you try running [OpenGL Extensions Viewer](http://realtech-vr.com/admin/glview). As far as I can tell by all this, is that you have no OpenGL support. Which sounds really weird. If you're using a virtual machine or executing the code remotely, then that could be the cause for problem as well. I am however assuming you're not doing that.

Comment: The graphics card is most likely too outdated. Which graphics card it is? This was in the back of my head, but the problem being that seems so unlikely. However now that you mention it being old, then that changes everything of course.

Comment: Thanks for your assistance, I have deleted my prior comments here and I think I have marked your answer as correct (I would also like it but apparently it is not counted the same way if I have less than 15 reputation). I will be looking into upgrading soon so I will be able to run more intensive things, such as OpenGL etc. and also for gaming purposes. I shall pay attention to OpenGL support when doing this as a result of this answer. Thanks again.